# Are there cases where using Web-based interface (in an organization) is inappropriate and why

Tags: web-applications, enterprise

For example, in the assembly line I have a feeling that it is inappropriate to use web application to log production status, though I don't have any reason to back it up.

In groceries stores or airport check-in counters for example, I notice that the software used to make purchases at the counter are mostly like a DOS-style interface (or can someone correct me on this). Why is this? Is it because of the cost of switching or something else?

Also, what makes web application a less attractive choice for businesses (or what makes it a more attractive choice)?

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for programming/coding problems. These kind of conceptual/architectural/opinionated questions are better asked in  programmers.stackexchange.com, and you may get better answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old school text style interfaces have stuck around in business both because of the cost of replacing those systems and because of the cost of retraining staff on entirely new software.

That being said, upgrading to web solutions is currently very attractive for enterprise software for two main reasons:

1. The capability of web UIs and the speed at which developers can prototype them has increased a lot over the last few years.
2. Deploying an update to a web app to an entire company only requires updating one place, and doesn't require relying on, for example, Citrix to do so.
3. Extending internal web apps to be used by actors external to the company intranet (eg. customers, subcontractors) is very easy.

A couple of instances where it wouldn't necessarily make sense to use a web application:

1. A lot of local CPU intensive data processing needs to be done (even then HTML5 would theoretically work).
2. A client app needing to be *always on*. It would be harder to enforce 'always keep this webpage open' than to just write a native service.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, DOS or green-screen interfaces are usually left over from the initial development of a pre-Windows application. If you need a new UI for non-technical people, generally it is easier to get one going on a Web browser rather messing with all of the fiddly little details of a native application.

Answer (score 1):

There are definite advantages of using a web application. Like that are cited above, ease of updates is the key advantage. A single update to the server is all what is required to propagate the changes to the systems connected. But the question arises what happens when there is an internet connection failure? If there is a fail over arrangement, then I think web application is the most convenient.